# orderBy not working with .startAfter(this.lastInResponse)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using pagination. On `ngOnInit()`, it is fetching data with proper ordering as expected, see code below -

```
    this.firestore.collection('complaints' , ref => ref 
.where("complaint_status", "==", "Open")
.limit(8)
.orderBy('ticketid', 'desc')
).snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(response => {
```

But whenI try to use this on clicking `NextPage()` function using below code, I dont receive any result

```
nextPage(){
        console.log("show next. data");
        this.disable_next = true;
        this.firestore.collection('complaints', ref => ref
        .where("complaint_status", "==", "Open")
        .limit(8) 
        .orderBy('ticketid', 'desc')
        .startAfter(this.lastInResponse)
        ).get()
```

Why am I not getting any result here? Note that if I remove order by, I do get results, but not getting with it on nextpage function.

Comment: So far, I see nothing wrong with your nextPage() function. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375231/firestore-startafter-returning-the-same-data-in-infinite-scrolling-when-ordere#answer-57386970) the startAfter() is expecting a query cursor for the parameter, which from your code seems to be lastInResponse. The information you provided does not include the value of the lastInResponse. I suggest you review that or update this thread with this info.

Comment: If i remove orderby, it works fine, if i add it, it doesnt return any data , what next should i do ?

Comment: Take a look at this post about Firestore + AngularFire2 pagination [1]. There is a section with examples using the Next Page method.

[1] https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50083771.shtml