# startAfter() not working even with last DocumentSnapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing basic pagination but `startAfter` isn't working as intended. I have attached a snippet of my function which returns the desired documents and the last document.

The first query is working fine and correct last document object is being returned. However, the second time I run this function with `lastVisible` variable set to the previously returned object the function returns exactly the same values as the first execution even though the `else` statement containing `startAfter` is executed.

I am using firebase-admin that's why I am not using newer methods like `getDoc` etc.

```js
export const fetchPosts = async (lastVisible, uid) => {
    if (!admin.apps.length)
        admin.initializeApp({
            credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
        })

    const db = getFirestore()
    try {
        let querySnap
        if (lastVisible === null)
            querySnap = await db.collection("posts").where("userId", "==", uid).orderBy("time", "desc").limit(2).get()
        else {
            querySnap = await db.collection("posts").where("userId", "==", uid).orderBy("time", "desc").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(2).get()
        }
        const lastDoc = querySnap.docs[querySnap.docs.length - 1]
        // console.log(typeof lastDoc)
        const docSnaps = querySnap.docs
        let data = []
        for (let i in docSnaps) {
            // console.log(docSnaps[i].data())
            data.push(docSnaps[i].data())
        }
        // console.log(data)
        // console.log(lastDoc)
        return { lastDoc: lastDoc, docs: data }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

This is what the `lastDoc` value is after first execution (some values have been altered by me here)

```js
{
  _fieldsProto: {
    title: { stringValue: 'test', valueType: 'stringValue' },
    time: { integerValue: '1656157500080', valueType: 'integerValue' },
    userId: {
      stringValue: 'YHX',
      valueType: 'stringValue'
    },
    postId: { stringValue: 'dJ4QY', valueType: 'stringValue' },
    text: {
      stringValue: 'ship',
      valueType: 'stringValue'
    }
  },
  _ref: {
    _firestore: { projectId: 'project-t' },
    _path: {
      segments: [Array],
      projectId: 'project-t',
      databaseId: '(default)'
    },
    _converter: {}
  },
  _serializer: { allowUndefined: false },
  _readTime: { _seconds: 1656332177, _nanoseconds: 366724000 },
  _createTime: { _seconds: 1656157500, _nanoseconds: 603745000 },
  _updateTime: { _seconds: 1656157500, _nanoseconds: 603745000 }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning snapshot of last document to `lastDoc` and not `lastVisible` so `lastVisible` would always be `null` unless you are reassigning a value from some where else that is not visible in provided code. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: @Dharmaraj `lastVisible` is the function parameter which is initially provided as `null` as there is no last visible document yet. `lastDoc` is being provided as parameter when function is executed the second time.

Comment: If you want to use last document's snapshot as cursor then it should be `startAt(lastDoc)`. What's the possible value of `lastVisible`?

Comment: I have added the complete function. First call, `fetchPosts(null, userId)`, the `lastDoc` return value is stored in a new variable, say `lastDocSnap`. The second call is then `fetchPosts(lastDocSnap, userId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64688485/10333905)

But it doesn't make sense when you look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). It says

> You can also pass a document snapshot to the cursor clause as the start or end point of the query cursor. The values in the document snapshot serve as the values in the query cursor.

That's what I was doing (at least in my opinion) but it wasn't working. So, instead of returning document snapshot I used the document itself and changed the `startAfter` query as follows

```js
// using document instead of documentSnapshot
const lastDoc = querySnap.docs[querySnap.docs.length - 1].data()

// modified query
querySnap = await db.collection("posts").where("userId", "==", uid).orderBy("time", "desc").startAfter(lastVisible.time).limit(2).get()
```